# How to run imageoptim from php on linux?

Tags: linux, image, optimization, compression

I was checking out [imageoptim](http://imageoptim.pornel.net/) today, and really would love to run this from php on my linux server. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

imageoptim is Mac OS X only. On there website they recommend [trimage](http://trimage.org/) for non  Mac users.

In order to call external programs from php you use the `exec` command documented [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

Note that for security reasons it is important to escape arguments passed to `exec` with another command like `escapeshellcmd` or `escapeshellarg` for security reasons.

Your assumption in the comment about command line options is correct, you just pass them along with the program name as the string argument to exec with proper escaping of course.

Comment: thanks for your comment, i assume i can just run trimage command line options via exec which is perfect for my use case.

Answer (score 5):

ImageOptim is no longer OS X-only. Now you can use the [ImageOptim Web API](https://imageoptim.com/api) on any platform.

Comment: this looks better than `trimage` and active developed